# Safari doesn't show titles for click throughs on google search results…

Tags: safari

Sometime recently -- maybe in the last month or so -- a glitch came up with Google and Safari 6. I don't know if it happened when I upgraded to Safari 6 or if it's the result of encrypted search results on Google.

[image: example search results]

As you can see here, when I search for something on Google, the history show that search. But when I click on a result, the history shows a crazy Google URL and does *not show the title of the site that I went to*, which makes it impossible to go back to something I was looking at earlier without randomly trying a bunch of different search results.

Any idea why this is happening, and how I can disable it? This is relatively new behavior. Between this and the new web inspector, I can't stand Safari anymore.

Comment: I did find gDirectLinks (http://canisbos.com/gdirectlinks) which rewrites links in google search results. As a side effect, it also fixes my particular problem. But my question still remains: what causes this, and is it affecting other? How has nobody at Google/Apple noticed this and fixed it already? I can only assume that it must be a rare problem.

Comment: Does the problem happen on other browsers too? I can’t check right now so tell me if you can.

Comment: No, it's not a problem in Chrome (no surprise there) or Firefox.

Comment: Interesting. I would like to see this problem solved. I tested it on my Mac and the problem happens with some searches but not with others. I can’t seem to find a pattern.

Comment: This also really annoys me. I often just re-run the search and look for the visited links, but it's kinda lame.

Comment: Is there anything we can do to help you out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Detox extension for Safari and Chrome](http://shauninman.com/archive/2012/01/19/detox), which fixes this on Google and Twitter.

This happens because Google switched to a client-side redirect for their tracking links (in JavaScript, I think) so the browser thinks the tracking page is the page you wanted. I'm not sure why. Twitter does the same thing, but it's so that they can grab the referer when you click on a t.co link from a client or another website.

Comment: Detox has stopped working for me recently, any other solutions?

Comment: @shawkinaw You could try contacting the author via [email](http://shauninman.com/contact/) or [Twitter](https://twitter.com/shauninman).

Comment: Try updating to Detox 1.2.3.